# Why can I not set the image of the embed to the attachment sent by the user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Making a command that allows a user to report a bug. I want it so you can include an image with the bug so you can show a visual example, except what I have does not work, and upon looking at the docs, this should work.

The problems I am having is that the embed is not sending. When I remove the `bugEmbed.set_image()` it works again.

```
@commands.command()
async def bug(self, ctx, *, bugReport=None):
    """Command that allows users to report bugs about the bug"""

    channel = self.client.get_channel(864211572218265610)

    bugEmbed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Bug Report",
        description=bugReport,
        color= 0xFFFF00
    )

    bugEmbed.add_field(
        name="Reported by",
        value=f"<@{ctx.author.id}>"
    )

    bugEmbed.set_footer(
        text="",
        icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url
    )
    bugEmbed.set_image(
        url=bugReport.attachments.url
    )

    if bugReport is None:
        await ctx.send("You didn't include a bug with the report! Try again.")

    await channel.send(embed=bugEmbed)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński ...? I don't know. That's the entire point of the question

Comment: Well it shouldn’t be. StackOverflow is not a debugging site. Sorry but I’m voting to close this question.

Comment: Who said I was asking for debugging? It's a question on why my code is not working because I am at a clear misunderstanding on how to get the image from a user and set it as the image for the embed. My post is what I have, and I thought it was correct  until actually trying the code out, realizing it is not correct and not understanding how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably related to `attachments` being a list so you can't access an attribute called url, meaning you would have to do something like this:

```py
if len(bugReport.attachments):
    bugEmbed.set_image(
        url=bugReport.attachments[0].url
    )
```

Edit:
Ok so the problem is you are trying to get the attachments from the `bugReport` which is just the text you pass, what you actually want to do is get that data from the context (ctx)

```py
if len(ctx.message.attachments):
    bugEmbed.set_image(
        url=ctx.message.attachments[0].url
    )
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work. Same problems occured.

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: No, same problems. I edited my post with more context on the exact issues.

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out and edited my answer

Comment: Fixed the problem! Thank you